# How to ask user for a series of number and return the sum of all numbers excluding the max number?

Tags: python, function, user-input

So I need to create a function in python that asks the user to input numbers and enter end when done. After that I need to compute the sum of the numbers enter excluding the max number. (i.e if the user entered 20, 50, and 100 the sum would be 70)

So for I have this which loops input until user inputs the word end:

```
def excludeMax():
   while True:
      result = input('Enter next number or end:')
      if (result == 'end'):
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks like what you are looking for.

```
def excludeMax():
   numbers = []
   while True:
      result = input('Enter next number or end:')
      if (result == 'end'):
        break
      else:
        numbers.append(result)
   # notice this is after the loop
   numbers.remove(max(numbers))
   return sum(numbers)
```

Comment: you can just `result.remove(max(numbers))`

Comment: @ozgur true, haven't practiced python in a while.

Answer (score 2):

Simply sort it and then add up a slice:

```
def exclude_max():
    return sum(sorted(map(int, iter(lambda: input('Enter next number or end: '), 'end')))[:-1])
```

Result:

```
>>> exclude_max()
Enter next number or end: 20
Enter next number or end: 50
Enter next number or end: 100
Enter next number or end: end
70
```

Comment: Calm down bro, I don't think he is supposed to use iterators or maps or lambdas in his homework xD

Comment: I think doing `end = 'end'` and `iter(lambda: input('Enter next number or end: '), end)` would be a better choice to prevent from getting `NameError: name 'end' is not defined` error in case user doesn't type `'end'` as string

Comment: @TigerhawkT2 can you please explain the lambda part, i got it why you giving 'end' to prevent NameError. but can you explain how its working

Comment: @Hackaholic - `iter()` can either create an iterator out of a single iterable, or it can create an iterator out of calling a function until that function returns the second passed argument. Since we want to pass a custom prompt to `input`, we need a `lambda` to wrap it. It will keep prompting until it gets `'end'`.

Comment: If the downvoter or someone else could tell me what's wrong with this answer, I would be happy to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop append all input values to a list (if not 'end'). After that sort list in place and compute sum for list[:-1] (gives you the list without the last element).

In code:

```
numbers = []
def excludeMax():
   while True:
       result = input('Enter next number or end:')
       if (result == 'end'):
           break
       else:
           numbers.append(result)
   numbers.sort()
   sum_numbers = sum(numbers[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Place all numerical input into a list. If you see an end, break from the `while` loop. Once you've exited the while loop, remove the max element from the list (e.g., `lst.remove(max(list))`). Finally, get the sum via `sum(lst)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:** No temp lists and sort needed in this approach. Excludes just one of the max numbers(doesn't deal with duplicates)

```
def excludeMax():
    biggest_sof_far = None
    sum_of_inputs = 0
    while True:
        result = input('Enter next number or end:')

        if result == 'end':
            break

        if biggest_sof_far == None:
            biggest_sof_far = result
        elif result > biggest_sof_far:
            sum_of_inputs += biggest_sof_far
            biggest_sof_far = result
        else:
            sum_of_inputs += result

    return sum_of_inputs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print excludeMax()
```

**Approach 2:** Using a temp list (increases space complexity) and sort and sum on  list(increases time complexity).  This to excludes just one max numbers(doesn't deal with duplicates)

```
def excludeMax():
    input_numbers = []
    while True:
        result = input('Enter next number or end:')

        if result == 'end':
            break

        input_numbers.append(result)

    input_numbers.sort()
    return sum(input_numbers[:-1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print excludeMax()
```

Both the approaches assume that you want to exclude just one max element.  If you want to exclude all max elements(in case of duplicate max numbers):

**Approach 1:** Excludes even the duplicate max numbers

```
def excludeMax():
    biggest_sof_far = None
    sum_of_inputs = 0
    while True:
        result = input('Enter next number or end:')

        if result == 'end':
            break

        if biggest_sof_far == None:
            biggest_sof_far = result
        elif result == biggest_sof_far:
            pass
        elif result > biggest_sof_far:
            sum_of_inputs += biggest_sof_far
            biggest_sof_far = result
        else:
            sum_of_inputs += result

    return sum_of_inputs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print excludeMax()
```

**Approach 2:** Excludes even the duplicate max numbers

```
def excludeMax():
    input_numbers = []
    while True:
        result = input('Enter next number or end:')

        if result == 'end':
            break

        input_numbers.append(result)

    input_numbers.sort()

    omit_till_index = -1
    input_len = len(input_numbers)

    while input_len > -omit_till_index and \
          input_numbers[omit_till_index] == input_numbers[omit_till_index-1]:
        omit_till_index = omit_till_index-1

    return sum(input_numbers[:omit_till_index])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print excludeMax()
```